# startAccelerometerUpdates in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cmmotionmanager

I found on an online tutorial this code:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (data, error) in
    }
```

The guy in the tutorial was using Swift 2, I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode gives me errors.
How do I "translate" this code from Swift 2 to Swift 4?
Thanks!

The guy also added another line of code that I would like to translate:

```
self?.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!), ((data?.acceleration.y)!))
```

How do I use it in Swift 4?

Tanks!

Comment: The syntax is the same in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)